# web service

Tags: web-services

I have web service, which use integrated security in IIS.
Now, I want to test my web service. 
I created a console application and adding web reference.
now, when i m trying to use web method. It show 401 error.
m i missing any authentication.
I think i need to pass user name and password programatically.
can anyone direct me in right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the web service credentials to the System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials in your console app

```
MyWebService proxy = new MyWebService();
proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

**Edit**

pass credentials programmatically:

```
MyWebService proxy = new MyWebService();
proxy.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domainname");
```

Comment: I have domainName\username and passwored.
how can i pass these credential programatically?

Comment: Are you referencing the web service on your local workstation or a remote server?

Comment: remote server.
i know user name and password.

Comment: You can used the first solution if you are trying to debug a web service on your local workstation

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your windows id on your desktop to the allowed users in IIS.

Comment: I can pass credential to pop up window, which appear on browser before accessing web service, and it work fine.
Now, i created a test console application, where i added web reference. and discover web service. But when i try to use web method within test application, it shows 401 error in cosole.